# Android dependency injection issue

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-injection

I have 3 library in my project named-A,B,C. A is the main library where my project starts. I add C library dependency in gradle of B because I need some activities of C in my library B. Then I add B libraray in gradle of A's dependency.
After adding it "getActionBar" in my project is becomes null .
Can any one one help me out from this??

Comment: this issue isn't dependent upon you libraries but looks like theme related, Have you set theme "NoActionBar" for your activity in Menifest?

Comment: @UsmanRana for both B and C library I add NoActionBar theme but I add requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); where I need ActionBar ..

Comment: Once you have applied NoActionBar  theme you can't request it as it doesn't exist in your activity now. Apply Actionbar theme and hide/show it where ever you want

Comment: @UsmanRana suppose in my B library I have number of activities named 1,2,3 and activity 1 have NoActionBar theme and have one button . After clicking that button I open one activity which extends FragmentActivity .In my fragmentActivty I call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) ...and when I call getActionBar in FragmentActivity it gives null

Comment: just change your theme to Actionbar from NoActionbar for the activity in which you are requesting it

Comment: @UsmanRana I have not applied any theme for fragment activity

Comment: show your Menifest file

Comment: @UsmanRana <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  package="myPackage">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
            android:name="com.hurix.fixedepubreader.PlayerActivityFixedLayout"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize|fontScale|screenLayout"
            android:theme="@style/CustomContextualActionBarThemeParent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: and what is parent of CustomContextualActionBarThemeParent ?
and try with getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar()

Comment: @UsmanRana parent of custom theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and in fragment Activity I am not getting getSupportActionBar , it shows error.

Comment: change theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and it will work for you. When you need to show actionbar the use getSupportActionBar().hide() or getSupportActionBar.show()